# Mysql WHERE conditional

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I have a table that looks like the one below, as you can see, there are only list of names.
Some has the same name as the others. My goal is, to count the total of each names with the same 'firstname' then do some conditional like IF(total_of_firstname >= 1 && total_of_firstname <= 20). Display the result. How can I achieve this using MySQL only?

```
|    id     |   firstname     |    lastname    |
|     1     |   Bob           |    Smith       |
|     2     |   Bob           |    Marley      |
|     3     |   Stacey        |    Clarke      |
|     4     |   Stacey        |    Witson      |
|     5     |   Stacey        |    Kowalowski  |
|     6     |   George        |    Benington   |
|     7     |   George        |    Robinson    |
```

Comment: Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it *should* work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Can you post the expected reasult for above data set here?

Comment: I have no clue how to achieve this, that's why I am asking

Comment: @user2310422 You should demonstrate your desired result.

Comment: My desire result is just plain and simple, if the total of 'Bob' or any firstname is somewhere between 1 and 20 display the results. Didn't I mention it above?

Answer (score 1):

First data:

```
CREATE TABLE `table`
 ( id int(11) auto_increment,
   firstname text, 
  lastname text,
  primary key (`id`)
 );


INSERT INTO `table` SET
 firstname = 'a',
 lastname = 'b';

INSERT INTO `table` SET
 firstname = 'a',
 lastname = 'c';

INSERT INTO `table` SET
 firstname = 'b',
 lastname = 'c';

INSERT INTO `table` SET
 firstname = 'c',
 lastname = 'c';

INSERT INTO `table` SET
 firstname = 'a',
 lastname = 'c';
```

Then SQL:

```
SELECT tablegrouped.firstname, tablegrouped.firstnamecount
FROM (
 SELECT firstname, count(*) as firstnamecount
 FROM table
 GROUP BY firstname) AS tablegrouped
WHERE tablegrouped.firstnamecount >=1 AND tablegrouped.firstnamecount <=20
```